# InnoDB foreign keys and MySQL partitioning

Tags: mysql, partition

I am usign MySQL Server version: 5.7.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (Ubuntu). In my DB i have this table with million records:

```
CREATE TABLE `tableA` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tableB_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_sjfet8dx50bhix3ub1dwocpcx` (`timestamp`,`tableB_id`),
  KEY `FK_su2f3awnwvdpq1h3x5x0drjaw` (`tableB_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_su2f3awnwvdpq1h3x5x0drjaw` FOREIGN KEY (`tableB_id`) REFERENCES `tableB` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Is it possible using PARTITIONING by RANGE (in this case by YEAR)?

Is it possible to partition even if a foreign key is present?

Thanks!

Comment: A million records is not a lot can I ask why you want to partition?

Comment: Sorry, that's several million records. I would like to partition the table to speed up some search and calculation queries. Queries are performed based on the 'timestamp' and some JOINs with other tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### NO.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-limitations.html says:

> Foreign keys not supported for partitioned InnoDB tables.  Partitioned tables using the InnoDB storage engine do not support foreign keys.

You can't partition this table by year anyway, because *every unique key on the table must use every column in the table's partitioning expression.*

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html for details on that.

Comment: Is there any way to partition with Foreign Keys too? I cannot delete it for the integrity of this data

Comment: Bill Karwin Could you push the validation into a trigger?

Comment: It's moot, because partitioning is not possible in the table shown in the question, for the second reason I described above.